# XPath accessing outer loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document with Records. Each record has a UI element and a TreeNum element. I'm trying to write an XSLT to generate the parent records from the parent tree numbers of each tree number in a record. The parent number is the tree number minus 1 digit, records with a tree number that are only 2 characters do not have a parent tree number. For example, the second record with UI "pear" has a tree number "A11", therefore it's parent tree number should be "A1". I would like to find the UI of the record that holds the parent tree number. So for the "pear" record, the parent record UI would be "apple".

**XML**

```
<RecordSet>
<Record>
    <UI>apple</UI>
    <TreeNum>A1</TreeNum>
    <TreeNum>A5</TreeNum>
</Record>

<Record>
    <UI>pear</UI>
    <TreeNum>A11</TreeNum>
</Record>

<Record>
    <UI>chocolate</UI>
    <TreeNum>A13</TreeNum>
    <TreeNum>A51</TreeNum>
</Record>
</RecordSet>
```

**XSL**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsd ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">    
        <xsl:for-each select = "RecordSet/Record">
            <Record>
                <UI><xsl:value-of select = "UI/text()"/></UI>
                <xsl:for-each select = "TreeNum">
                    <TreeNumber><xsl:value-of select = "text()"/></TreeNumber>
                    <xsl:if test = "string-length(text()) > 2">
                        <ParentUI><xsl:value-of select = "../Record[UI/text() = substring(TreeNum/text(), 0, string-length(text())-1)]/UI[text()]"/></ParentUI>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected Output**

```
    <Record xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
   <UI>apple</UI>
   <TreeNumber>A1</TreeNumber>
   <TreeNumber>A5</TreeNumber>
</Record>
<Record xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
   <UI>pear</UI>
   <TreeNumber>A11</TreeNumber>
   <ParentUI>apple</ParentUI>
</Record>
<Record xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
   <UI>chocolate</UI>
   <TreeNumber>A13</TreeNumber>
   <ParentUI>apple</ParentUI>
   <TreeNumber>A51</TreeNumber>
   <ParentUI>apple</TreeNumber>
</Record>
```

I have tried to look online for a solution however I find this problem difficult to describe and therefore hard to search for a solution. I appreciate any help and will try to clarify more if needed.

The XPath I have used to select the parent UI does not work and returns an empty ParentUI element, so it's the XPath expression that is incorrect, I have tried using a variable to select the record element in the outer loop and the "../" operator but with no luck selecting what I need.

Comment: Note that the result you show is an **XML fragment**. A well-formed XML document must have a single root element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsd ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="rec" match="Record" use="TreeNum" />

<xsl:template match="/RecordSet">    
    <xsl:for-each select="Record">
        <Record>
            <xsl:copy-of select="UI"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="TreeNum">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:variable name="parent" select="key('rec', substring(., 1, string-length(.) - 1))" />
                <xsl:if test="$parent">
                    <ParentUI>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$parent/UI"/>
                    </ParentUI>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Record>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try with :

```
<ParentUI><xsl:value-of select = "./preceding::UI[following-sibling::TreeNum[.=substring(.,1,2)]]"/></ParentUI>
```

Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
   <UI>apple</UI>
   <TreeNumber>A1</TreeNumber>
   <TreeNumber>A5</TreeNumber>
</Record>
<Record xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
   <UI>pear</UI>
   <TreeNumber>A11</TreeNumber>
   <ParentUI>apple</ParentUI>
</Record>
<Record xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
   <UI>chocolate</UI>
   <TreeNumber>A13</TreeNumber>
   <ParentUI>apple</ParentUI>
   <TreeNumber>A51</TreeNumber>
   <ParentUI>apple</ParentUI>
</Record>
```

Comment: Did not produce the correct output upon changing tree number values unfortunately

Comment: OK. Output seemed correct to me : http://xsltransform.net/nbssZva